# Resetting Azure Durable Function Debug Options in VSCode

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I recently began debugging an Azure Durable Function in VSCode and initially selected the local emulator as the debugging option. Unfortunately, this didn't work as expected, and I'd prefer to debug using an Azure storage account. Is there a way to reset the debug options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the same in my environment.

**Steps followed:**

- Created Python Durable Function.
- Initially, I have selected Local Emulator as Storage.

[image]

- After selecting Local Emulator, I could see `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` as been assigned to `"AzureWebJobsStorage"` setting in **local.settings.json**.

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

To reset and debug the Function with Azure storage account, modify local.settings.json as below:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "", //removed assigned value UseDevelopmentStorage=true
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

- Click **F5** (or) Select `Debug: Start Debugging` in Command Palette(ctrl+shift+p), a dialogue box will be displayed to select the Storage account.

[image]

- Select your Storage account from the displayed list or create a new one.

[image]

- Able to the debug the durable function with Azure Storage account successfully:

[image]